# How to solve an error "android Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of"?

Tags: php, android, getjson

i'm using AsyncTask to parse JSON from server. but, i got a problem when i run my apps. in my logcat, my JSON looks fine but after that there is an error message `android Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`. i've already tried some suggestions from forums but i wasn't still get the best way to solve this. here my code :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_level_detaildatamerchant, "GET", params);
        Log.d("Get List :", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    Pk_Merchant_ID = c.getString(TAG_Pk_Merchant_ID);
                    Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID = c.getString(TAG_Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID);
                    Fk_Ms_City_ID = c.getString(TAG_Fk_Ms_City_ID);
                    Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_CreatedBy = c.getString(TAG_Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_CreatedBy);
                    Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_LastUpdateBy = c.getString(TAG_Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_LastUpdateBy);
                    CreatedDated = c.getString(TAG_CreatedDated);
                    LastUpdateDated = c.getString(TAG_LastUpdateDated);
                    Descriptions = c.getString(TAG_Descriptions);
                    Address = c.getString(TAG_Address);
                    Telpon = c.getString(TAG_Telpon);
                    Handphone = c.getString(TAG_Handphone);
                    BB_PIN = c.getString(TAG_BB_PIN);
                    email = c.getString(TAG_email);
                    Longitude = c.getString(TAG_Longitude);
                    Latitude = c.getString(TAG_Latitude);
                    Path_PhotoProfile = c.getString(TAG_Path_PhotoProfile);
                    Is_Deleted = c.getString(TAG_Is_Deleted);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_Pk_Merchant_ID, Pk_Merchant_ID);
                        map.put(TAG_Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID, Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID);
                        map.put(TAG_Fk_Ms_City_ID, Fk_Ms_City_ID);
                        map.put(TAG_Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_CreatedBy, Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_CreatedBy);
                        map.put(TAG_Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_LastUpdateBy, Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_LastUpdateBy);
                        map.put(TAG_CreatedDated, CreatedDated);
                        map.put(TAG_LastUpdateDated, LastUpdateDated);
                        map.put(TAG_Descriptions, Descriptions);
                        map.put(TAG_Address, Address);
                        map.put(TAG_Telpon, Telpon);
                        map.put(TAG_Handphone, Handphone);
                        map.put(TAG_BB_PIN, BB_PIN);
                        map.put(TAG_email, email);
                        map.put(TAG_Longitude, Longitude);
                        map.put(TAG_Latitude, Latitude);
                        map.put(TAG_Path_PhotoProfile, Path_PhotoProfile);
                        map.put(TAG_Is_Deleted, Is_Deleted);
                    listData.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and this is my php :

```
    <?php
    $response = array();

    $dsn='sqlserver';
    $username='street'; 
    $password='keymaker';

    $koneksi= odbc_connect($dsn,$username,$password);

    if (isset($_POST['Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID'])) {

    $Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID = $_POST['Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID'];

    $query = "select * from Ms_Merchant where Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID = '$Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID' ";

    $result = odbc_exec($koneksi, $query);

        $response ["Ms_Merchant"] = array();
        WHILE  ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
            $Ms_Merchant = array();
                $Ms_Merchant["Pk_Merchant_ID"] = $row ["Pk_Merchant_ID"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID"] = $row ["Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Fk_Ms_City_ID"] = $row ["Fk_Ms_City_ID"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_CreatedBy"] = $row ["Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_CreatedBy"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_LastUpdateBy"] = $row ["Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_LastUpdateBy"];
                $Ms_Merchant["CreatedDated"] = $row ["CreatedDated"];
                $Ms_Merchant["LastUpdateDated"] = $row ["LastUpdateDated"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Descriptions"] = $row ["Descriptions"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Address"] = $row ["Address"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Telpon"] = $row ["Telpon"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Handphone"] = $row ["Handphone"];
                $Ms_Merchant["BB_PIN"] = $row ["BB_PIN"];
                $Ms_Merchant["email"] = $row ["email"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Longitude"] = $row ["Longitude"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Latitude"] = $row ["Latitude"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Path_PhotoProfile"] = $row ["Path_PhotoProfile"];
                $Ms_Merchant["Is_Deleted"] = $row ["Is_Deleted"];
            array_push($response["Ms_Merchant"], $Ms_Merchant);
        }
        $response["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    odbc_close($koneksi);
    ?>
```

i need your all of your helps. thank you for advance.

Comment: You are probably getting a blank response. Its not null but the response is empty. So you are getting this error and not a Nullpointer exception

Comment: can you explain more detail that related with my code ?